# Apache hadoop Java API - Difference between Text.readFields() vs Text.readString()

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to understand the difference between `Text.readFields()` vs `Text.readString()` in [`Text`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.4/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/Text.html#readString(java.io.DataInput,%20int)) class.

From the [javadoc](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.4/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/Text.html#readString(java.io.DataInput,%20int)), it is not very clear. The only slight hint is about that probably `Text.readString()` do perform UTF-8 encoding, which is evident from the actual implementation

```
467  /** Read a UTF8 encoded string with a maximum size
468   */
469  public static String readString(DataInput in, int maxLength)
470      throws IOException {
471    int length = WritableUtils.readVIntInRange(in, 0, maxLength);
472    byte [] bytes = new byte[length];
473    in.readFully(bytes, 0, length);
474    return decode(bytes);
475  }


294  public void readFields(DataInput in, int maxLength) throws IOException {
295    int newLength = WritableUtils.readVInt(in);
296    if (newLength < 0) {
297      throw new IOException("tried to deserialize " + newLength +
298          " bytes of data!  newLength must be non-negative.");
299    } else if (newLength >= maxLength) {
300      throw new IOException("tried to deserialize " + newLength +
301          " bytes of data, but maxLength = " + maxLength);
302    }
303    readWithKnownLength(in, newLength);
304  }
```

Another difference is in the signature of the methods.  `readString()` is static, while other is not.

Now I have below doubts:

1. Am I missing something else?
2. As far I know, Strings follows UTF encoding standard in Java API. What may be the condition when `readString()` and `readFields()` makes difference? Other way when should I use one instead of another.
3. Why one is static and another is not? What difference it makes and when one should be used over another in this `Text` class context (class vs object level method)?

Comment: Regarding static methods, you obviously don't need an instance of a Text object to call it, and it returns a value rather than setting a member variable... Anyway, you might want to focus on `readVIntInRange` vs `readVInt`

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks, would dig more and update if found something.